# iterating a list in jsp using spring mvc

Tags: list, jsp, spring-mvc

```
Hii i am trying to get the values of a list on jsp

<core:forEach items="${loginsuccess}" var="items">
<core:out value="${items}">

</core:out>

in this code tegre are three entries or more than one
```

i wint to show in one and than other in new line but it shows one after another in a single line so please tell how can i do this
i wint to show in one and than other in new line but it shows one after another in a single line so please tell how can i do this

Comment: Your naming of attributes is very confusing. Is `items` the collection or `loginsuccess`? From the naming I would assume that `items` is the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<core:forEach items="${loginsuccess}" var="items">
   <core:out value="${items}"/><br/>
</core:forEach>
```

Comment: hello @ Ramesh  thanks for this i have one more problem in tyhis list i have two elements notification and boolean isnew so i just want to show notification so can it be plzz rply foir this